# Poisoning my own food?

Tags: halacha, food, halacha-theory, gezel-stealing

I live in an apartment with roommates, I'm trying to determine who is stealing my food. I use the word stealing because each of us had have our own separate and color-coded cabinets, and I also label all my food.

For a situation like this, what does *halacha* say about the permissibility of "poisoning" one's own food in a way that produces a noticable effect without doing harm?  The goal is to identify the thief by seeing who, say, breaks out into a sneezing fit.

(For practical advice, of course consult your own rabbi.)

Comment: Rabbi J David Bleich has a lengthy article in *Tradition* about precisely this, "The Case of the Poisoned Sandwich." Practically -- STAY AWAY FROM POISON!! DO NOT DO IT!!

Comment: you can read it here: http://traditionarchive.org/news/article.cfm?id=105386

Comment: I would not advise it. Put in a hidden camera.

Comment: @CashCow It is often hard to hide a camera in a sandwich. And then, once it is eaten, it often stops transmitting.

Comment: in the fridge, or the room with the fridge in it. Simplest though would be to get a lockable box.

Comment: The first point of call to stop my house being burgled is good locks. Next step is a burglar alarm. Putting in boobie traps and electric wires or whatever would be a very last resort.

Comment: @Danno You could use [one of these](http://www.givenimaging.com/en-int/innovative-solutions/capsule-endoscopy/pages/default.aspx) and then identify the perpetrator by intestinal features.

Comment: @IsaacMoses true -- they say that each colon is unique.

Comment: Sounds like @CashCow is on the "money" with his idea (no pun intended ;-). I think he meant, like a web cam, so you can record the action. A similar idea may be using some type of powder or invisible ink that leaves fingerprints. The ink would have to stay on a while so that you can compare it with the same fingerprints left in, say the rest room after you know that person has used it. Or, you could shake his / her hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rabbi J. David Bleich addresses it in ["The Case of the Poisoned Sandwich", *Tradition* 41:3](http://traditionarchive.org/news/article.cfm?id=105386). There are one or two Israeli poskim who are gung-ho about taking the law into your own hands, but practically I advise against it in the strongest of terms.

The Vilna Gaon's reading of the Yerushalmi, Dmai 3:5 is that you make take no action that will cause harm to someone else -- even if that harm is triggered by the other fellow's malfeasance. (The example there is for you to give a pound of non-kosher flour to a cook who may swap it for someone else's flour.) This would apply to the case here of poisoning your own sandwich.

Comment: Would laxatives or the like be included in "harm"?

Comment: @mevaqesh sounds like it would. The problem with ANY medications, esp. OTC's is that you don't know who is allergic or has negative reactions to something. Even my own doctor doesn't know that I have a bad reaction to a combo of an OTC with one of his prescribed meds, and he's a doctor! Kal vachomer trying this if you're NOT a doctor!